# Sprite array loop only shows 1 element

Tags: c++, arrays, sprite, sfml

Trying to get 4 clouds to move across the screen left to right. When I execute  I can see all 4 clouds are drawn at the positions given in the code. But after game starts only one cloud is moving across the screen; the other 3 never show.

```
const int NUM_CLOUDS = 4;
Sprite clouds[NUM_CLOUDS];
int position = 0;
```

In main:

```
Texture textureCloud;
textureCloud.loadFromFile("graphics/cloud.png");
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CLOUDS; i++)
{
    clouds[i].setTexture(textureCloud);
    clouds[i].setPosition(0, position);
    position += 100;
}
bool cloudsActive[NUM_CLOUDS];
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CLOUDS; i++)
{
    cloudsActive[i] = false;
}
float cloudSpeed[NUM_CLOUDS];
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CLOUDS; i++)
{
    cloudSpeed[i] = 0.0f;
}

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CLOUDS; i++)
{
   if (!cloudsActive[i])
   {
      srand((int)time(0) * 30);
      cloudSpeed[i] = (rand() % 200);
      srand((int)time(0) * 30);
      float height = (rand() % 450) - 150;
      clouds[i].setPosition(-200, height);
      cloudsActive[i] = true;
   }
   else
   {
      clouds[i].setPosition(clouds[i].getPosition().x + (cloudSpeed[i] * dt.asSeconds()), clouds[i].getPosition().y);
      if (clouds[i].getPosition().x > 1920)
      {
         cloudsActive[i] = false;
      }
   }
```

}

Comment: I do not know if it is the cause, but your program should only call `srand` once, to seed the random number generator. It looks like it is resetting the seed everytime you need a random number, resulting in the same random number.

Also, ideally if you are on C++11 or newer you should also be using C++'s standard random library.

Comment: ...In other words, you are showing all four clouds, but they all have the same position so they look like one clouds since they are drawn overtop of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are srand-ing every time before you rand. You're probably seeding with the same number every time, because not enough time has passed between calls to srand to change the number. Calling rand() depends deterministically, usually, on the random seed. This means if you call rand() multiple times, each time setting the seed to the same number, you'll get the same number back from rand(). This makes all the clouds get the same parameters, so they display right on top of one another, and you only see them as one cloud. To fix, call srand() only once near the beginning of your program. Also, as @ColonD said, you should be using C++ random numbers if you're in C++11 or newer: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random .

Answer (score 0):

Clouds are not disappeared they are just at same position due to error in code.

Rather then this

```
srand((int)time(0) * 30)
```

You should use

```
srand((int)time(0)*i * 30)
```

Where 'i' is your number declared in loop.

Explanation ->

Time between two loops is too short that you cannot use it as int so multiplying it with different number every time can change the seed and fix your bug.